# Not proper alignment for nodes in a `TikZ` diagram (Version 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code renders a diagram of a number line. I have -8, a, e, and 10 labeled on it. (I magnified the figure by 3/4.) The labels that are typeset from the node commands for a, e, and 10 are aligned perfectly along a green horizontal line under them. Why is -8 not aligned on this same horizontal line?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (-8) at ({(3/4)*(-4)},0);
\coordinate (a) at ({(3/4)*-2.5},0);
\coordinate (b) at ({(3/4)*(-1)},0);
\coordinate (c) at ({(3/4)*0.5},0);
\coordinate (d) at ({(3/4)*2},0);
\coordinate (e) at ({(3/4)*3.5},0);
\coordinate (10) at ({(3/4)*5},0);

%The labels for -8 and 10 are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] (label_for_-8) at ($(-8) +(0,-0.15)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0]  (label_for_10) at ($(10) +(0,-0.15)$){10};

%The labels for a, b, c, d, and e are typeset.
\draw[green,  name path=a_path_for_the_label_a_e] (label_for_-8.south) -- (label_for_10.south);
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_a] (a) -- ($(a) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_a and a_path_for_the_label_a_e, by=label_for_a}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_a){\textit{a}};
\path[name path=path_for_the_label_e] (e) -- ($(e) +(0,-0.5)$);
\path[name intersections={of=path_for_the_label_e and a_path_for_the_label_a_e, by=label_for_e}];
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at (label_for_e){\textit{e}};


%The number line is drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] ({(3/4)*(-5)},0) -- ({(3/4)*6},0);


%Tick marks are drawn.
\draw ($(-8) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(-8) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(a) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(a) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(b) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(b) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(c) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(c) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(d) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(d) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(e) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(e) +(0,-2pt)$);
\draw ($(10) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(10) +(0,-2pt)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is not horizontal.

If you add `draw` to the options of the `-8` and `10` nodes, you will see that the first of those has some depth, i.e. there is some whitespace below the 8. This is not present in the second one.

A simple fix is to use the `base` anchor instead of the `south` anchor when drawing the green line, i.e.

```
\draw[green,name path=a_path_for_the_label_a_e] (label_for_-8.base) -- (label_for_10.base);
```

See for example:

[image]

Here the green line is drawn between the `south` anchors, and the red one between the `base` anchors, and the borders of the nodes are drawn, so you can see the whitespace below the 8.

---

Of course, you can do this with a lot less code, not making all the dummy paths down from each coordinate and calculating intersections. The coordinate that has the y-value of `a` and the x-value of `b` is given by `(a -| b)`, so you can do e.g.

```
\node [anchor=base] at (label_for_-8.base -| a) {\textit{a}};
```

to place a node with `\textit{a}` such that the baseline of this node is at the same y-value as the baseline of the `-8` node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (-8) at ({(3/4)*(-4)},0);
\coordinate (a) at ({(3/4)*-2.5},0);
\coordinate (b) at ({(3/4)*(-1)},0);
\coordinate (c) at ({(3/4)*0.5},0);
\coordinate (d) at ({(3/4)*2},0);
\coordinate (e) at ({(3/4)*3.5},0);
\coordinate (10) at ({(3/4)*5},0);

%The labels for -8 and 10 are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] (label_for_-8) at ($(-8) +(0,-0.15)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}8};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0]  (label_for_10) at ($(10) +(0,-0.15)$){10};

\draw [green,very thin] (label_for_-8.base) -- (label_for_10.base);

%The labels for a, b, c, d, and e are typeset.
\foreach \x in {a,...,e}
   \node [anchor=base] at (label_for_-8.base -| \x) {\textit{\x}};

%The number line is drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] ({(3/4)*(-5)},0) -- ({(3/4)*6},0);

%Tick marks are drawn.
\foreach \x in {-8,a,b,c,d,e,10}
  \draw ($(\x) +(0,2pt)$) -- ($(\x) +(0,-2pt)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your modification to the code in the post is what I wanted.

Comment: Why is there some white space surrounding `-8` but not `10`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Seems the `\makebox` has some depth.

Comment: What is the difference between `(label_for_-8.base)` and `(label_for_-8.south)`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire `base` is at the baseline of the text, `south` is the bottom of the node.